# Is Request Sync feature required for Actions approval process

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

We developed a Google Smart Home action and want to send it for the approval process. For the last three months, Google changes testing criteria and published an automated test for verifying your action before submit https://smarthome-test-suite.appspot.com/. Now I see that one of the features which are tested is a Request Sync feature. Is it possible to pass the Google Verification process without Request Sync being implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/request-sync):

> Note: You must implement Request Sync in order to submit a smart home Action.